# How to get environment variables into a bash array?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

In bash, how can I get all environment variables into an array variable?

I tried the following:

```
readarray -d "" env_vars <<< "$(env -0)"
```

This fails with

```
-bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
```

Note that an environment variable may contain a multi-line string. Therefore splitting on EOL does not give the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(...)` expands to a string, and strings can't have zero bytes.

Do not use `<<<$(...)`, when you can use `< <(...)`.

```
readarray -d "" env_vars < <(env -0)
```

Comment: ./start.sh: line 7: syntax error: unexpected redirection shucks

Comment: @DeanHiller You are not using bash.